# How to say "lacquer" when talking about food?

Tags: translation, words, food, jargon

I found that the term 漆塗り or simply 漆 is used to indicated the lacquer applied to materials such as wood, but can I use the same term in a food context? I am talking about that sort of 'glaze' you can find in recipes such as [this one](https://debfabfood.wordpress.com/2014/08/08/lacquered-salmon/). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most generic terms would be:

Noun: 艶{つや}、ツヤ

Noun: 艶/ツヤ出{だ}し  ← act of creating/adding ツヤ

Verb: 艶/ツヤを出す

The words グレーズ and グレーズド are **not** nearly as common.  In fact, many would not even be familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is 照り焼き. For example, here's a recipe for 鮭の照り焼き:

https://www.orangepage.net/recipes/detail_121725

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think teriyaki is a specific lacquering method. I am looking for a more general term, if there is one.

Comment: The word グレーズ and グレーズド are also used. Are you familiar with Cookpad? It's a huge Japanese recipe site, and a good place to learn culinary terms in Japanese.